# How to debug crash caused by calling deleteLater on a QObject derived class?

Tags: qt

I have a large class that is derived from QObject. The class contains many different types of children which have many connections to various QObject derived classes. When I try to call deleteLater() on the large class, I get a crash subsequently further down the code. When I add print statements to debug the location of the crash, the console output shows that location of crash changes each time I add a different print statement. Not calling deleteLater() prevents the crash from happening, but it is taking up memory space and this class is frequently created through user interaction.

Sometimes during the crash the console will output the error "QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver". Is the problem caused by still active connections within the children of the class? But calling deleteLater() on the large class should also cause the children to be deleted and their connections deleted as well. What can I do to debug the crash since print statements aren't effective?

Comment: You almost certainly have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code.  Without seeing the code there's really not much more that can be said I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on what you meant by undefined behaviour?

Comment: See for example [`cppreference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Build the debug version of your app, then run the app with debugger to see on what line the program crashes. Then go up the call stack to find where the code possibly got wrong. As G.M. writes, without seeing your code nobody can help you.

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager The debug version is not runnable on the qml code for various reasons, so I can't use the debugger to debug.

Comment: @ablan Then you should do everything you can to make it runnable in debugger. Developing without debugger is literally impossible. Debugger is one of the mightiest tools you have as a developer.